# How to make pagination with categoryid in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have the following routing system in my

```
http://localhost/myproject/controller.
```

When I filtring records using categoryid that have in second segment like:

```
http://localhost/myproject/controller/id.
```

I have a routing like this:

```
$route['routingcontroller/(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1';
```

How my controller looks like

```
public function index()
{
    // Which records we want
    $id = $this->uri->segment(2);

    // Pagination starts
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'routingcontroller/'.$id;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Product_model->count_total_records($id);
    $config['per_page'] = 12;

    // Customization
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'per_page';

    if ($this->uri->segment(2)) {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(2);
    } else {
        $offset = 0;
    }

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['configure'] = $this->Home_Model->configures();
    $data['main_menu'] = $this->Home_Model->main_menu();
    $data['social_media'] = $this->Home_Model->social_media();
    $data['testimonials'] = $this->Home_Model->testimonials();
    $data['category'] = $this->Product_model->category();
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->products($id, $config['per_page'], $offset);
    $data['main_content'] = 'viewfile';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

When I click pagination links that is display like

```
http://localhost/myproject/id/pageno
```

Then I get an error message like this:

```
404 Page Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in route

```
$route['routingcontroller/(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1'; 
$route['routingcontroller/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'controller/index/$1/$2';
```

in controller

```
public function index($id){
  // $id will be available
  // for page_no $this->uri->segment(3)
  // all code as it is
}
```

Comment: My URI segment is getting two not three

Comment: Okay, I not getting any errors right now, but the problem is when I paginate on page numbers it only moves no of pages records.

Comment: @mukesh_patel  you will be able to get the id and page_no,its all up to you how to work with them.